# Array.from vs new Set

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

In JavaScript, creating an array from a collection is done with `Array.from(collection)`, but creating a `Set` from a collection is done with `new Set(collection)`. Is there a reason for this asymmetry?

Comment: Array is a very special "collection" type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Array` constructor can be called in two ways:

```
new Array(n)
```

where `n` is an integer. This creates an array with `n` undefined elements.

```
new Array(e1, e2, e3, ...)
```

This creates an array whose elements are `e1`, `e2`, `e3`, etc., similar to writing

```
[e1, e2, e3, ...]
```

When you call the constructor with one argument, if it's not an integer it's treated as a case of the second format. This creates an array with one element whose value is the argument.

So if you do `new Array(collection)`, it creates an array whose first element is the collection. Changing this to spread the collection would be an incompatible change that might break some programs. So they defined a new method that does this.